# Prove or disprove. Improper integral

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

Let $f:[1, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$. If $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1}^{n}f$, $n\in \mathbb N$ exists  then $\int_{1}^{\infty} f$ exists

I´m having a really hard time with this problem. I haven´t been able to prove it or give a counterexample.

I would really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: The first limit is for $x \to 1$?

Comment: This is a *definition* of the improper Riemann integral, and not a problem.

Comment: Why is it a definition?

Comment: You are right, it´s when $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: $\int_1^x f = \int_1^{[x]} f + \int_{[x]}^x f$, where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. The last integral goes to $0$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: why the last integral goes to zero?

Comment: The length of the interval is less than 1, and you can always bound $|f(x)|$ with arbitrary small $\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $x$.